# BlueZ GATT programming in C

Tags: c, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I am trying to read data from TI SensorTag from a bluetooth enabled linux PC using C programming. But I didn't get any programming API of bluez so that I can discover BLE profile and GATT profile to get sensor reading. There is  no documentation I found. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: The best way to understand is to download the bluez source code and pick apart the `gatttool`.  It's written in C.

Comment: I am trying but at least there should be a documentation for that. From source code it is very tough and time consuming. Also hell lot of dependencies are there

Comment: Yes!  I know!  But it is what it is.  All the documentation is around using the DBUS interface which doesn't handle unique attributes such as the accelerometer on the SensorTag.  The gatttool has a function for each argument you can pass to it, so you just have to find the function doing the thing you want and figure that out.

Comment: I am having another problem with yocto. the glib is not working, rather say bluez not recognizing it although it is installed. hence I am unable to do a single code even if I try to understand bluez source codes

Comment: well, that's a completely different question...  one I wouldn't be able to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

I am caught by this problem for a long time.It's hard for me to read bluez's code.
Today I found a python library implement some gatt function simply which only need you to give simple parametres unlike bluez(it needs some parametres which are hard to understand).[there's a src in it where you maybe you can read to understand the .cpp to programm you .c](https://github.com/rh389/pygattlib)
hope useful~

Comment: C is better for resource constrained devices